# build a function for which the cumulative sum is bigger or equal to some constant

Tags: r, function, cumulative-sum

I have a vector which has n elements. The sum of the elements is 1. I would like a function that take as input the vector and return the number of vector's elements such that their sum is bigger or equal to 0.80.
For instance, consider the following vector:

```
A <- as.matrix(c(0.5, 0.2, 0.15, 0.10, 0.05))
```

The function has to return 3, because 0.5 + 0.2 + 0.15 >= 0.80

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
csum_index <- function(v, t=0.8) which(cumsum(v) >= t)[1]
```

The above function returns the first index of a vector `v` at which the cumulative sum of its elements is larger than or equal to `t`. The default value of `t` is 0.8.

```
csum_index(A)
#[1] 3
csum_index(A,0.9)
#[1] 4
```